# Running Jenkins job after merge request in Gitlab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use a Gitlab web hook to trigger a job in Jenknis after pushing a commit/opening a merge commit using a pipeline script.

For some reason, Jenkins always checks out the master branch and builds it. How
can I specify which branch to build using the Groovy script?

I tried to use the environment variable from the Gitlab POST request, but it still always uses the master branch:

```
checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM' , branches: [[name:'origin/${env.gitlabSourceBranch}']], browser: [$class 'GitLab', repoUrl: 'some-git-repo.com', version: 9.0], doGenerateSubmoduleConfiguration: false, extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption' disableSubmodules: false, parentCredentials: true, recursiveCredentials: true, recursiveSubmodules: true, reference: '', trackingSubmodules: false], [$class: 'PrebuildMerge', options: [fastForwardMode: 'FF', mergeRemote: '', mergeTarget: 'origin/${env.gitlabTargetBranch}']]], submodulecfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '12345', url: 'git@some-git-repo.com:A/repo.git']]]
```

(I generated this command using the snippet generator)

Comment: Please edit your post and add your code, what you tried so far so we can help you solve your problem faster.

Comment: Have You included your another branch in script for execution, can you show the script you have writen

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Generic Webhook trigger" plugin in Jenkins.
It allows you to get the branch name from the POST request sent by Gitlab, map it as a variable and use it inside your pipeline.

Configuration:

[image]

Inside the pipeline:

```
stage('Clone sources') {
        steps {
            git credentialsId: '...', poll: false, branch: ${branch}, url: '...'
        }
    }
```

Full example at: https://pillsfromtheweb.blogspot.com/2021/10/trigger-jenkins-on-merge-request-from.html